# Solidity Code Formatting in PHP Storm

Tags: solidity, ide, formatting

I have recently changed my IDE from VSCode to **PHPStorm** for some extra features that I found on it. However now I am facing some **issues for coding in Solidity**, the one that affects me the most being having **no code formatting**.

On the Solidity Plugin https://github.com/intellij-solidity/intellij-solidity for the IDE **I found that it formats the code, however, after installation I have it no option to format** (maybe I lack doing some set up?)

I have even **set up Prettier on PHPStorm** (with the .sol type included), it is working on other files such as `.tsx, .js, .ts, .vue` but I keep getting the error:

```
Prettier: File Raffle.sol has unsupported type
```

I would appreciate some knowledge here, **I would like to know if it is possible or not to somehow format my Solidity code on PHPStorm right now**.

Thank you very much!